# SELECT Multiple Columns FROM a subquery (placed in the SELECT Clues) Efficiently

Tags: sql-server, count, subquery

I have 3 tables:

1. TableA
2. TableB
3. TableC

I need to do a couple of aggregate functions (COUNT and SUM) on some Columns from them.

I didn't find a way to join them together (even with the ClientId Column below) so I tried:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA 
WHERE ClientId = 2 AND IsDisabled != 1 AND IsDeleted != 1) AS ColumnName1, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableB 
WHERE ClientId = 2 AND DisabledWhen IS NULL) AS ColumnName2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableC
WHERE ClientId = 2 AND TDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -30) AS ColumnName3,
(SELECT SUM(TPrice + COALESCE (PPrice,0)) FROM TableC
WHERE ClientId = 2 AND TDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -30) AS ColumnName4;
```

and it's working, the result is:

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| ColumnName1  | ColumnName2 | ColumnName3 | ColumnName4  |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 202          | 86          | 25          | 4574.0000    |    
+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

but I want to combine the last two subqueries to be one subquery.

So I tried to do this:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS ColumnName3, SUM(TPrice + COALESCE (PPrice,0)) AS ColumnName4 FROM TableC
WHERE ClientId = 2 AND TDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -30);
```

but I get this error:

*Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced EXISTS*.

How do I get Multiple columns from one subquery?

and what is the efficient way to do the above query?

Comment: If you are doing this for a single clientid then the question has been answered. If you want a query across multiple clients then there is probably a better way to do it using joins between the tables. But you would have to give us some info on the schema for us to answer that.

Comment: @TOMC this is for a single clientid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the query on `TableC` to the outer most select, keeping the first two subqueries as they are now:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA 
     WHERE ClientId = 2 AND IsDisabled != 1 AND IsDeleted != 1) AS ColumnName1, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableB 
    WHERE ClientId = 2 AND DisabledWhen IS NULL) AS ColumnName2,
    COUNT(*) AS ColumnName3,
    SUM(TPrice + COALESCE (PPrice, 0)) AS ColumnName4
FROM TableC
WHERE
    ClientId = 2 AND
    TDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30;
```

This works because the first two subqueries are basically treated as constants.  The remainder of the query to function on `TableC` alone, letting us select multiple aggregates.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working good! is it efficient in large tables?

Comment: Actually, this is not a very efficient method, you can use just primary key columns in count function, like COUNT(Id). But at this point you must consider why you need this, please check the whole architecture, if tthis is a kind of report or something like that this is the efficient method only you have.

Comment: @Dogan To the contrary, if the OP wants 4 counts from 3 different tables, this method is efficient and only requires scanning each of the three tables once.

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen, at first glance you are right but then I think that where criteria at the end of the tableC looks like returning many rows, so do not it means sub queries will be executed as much as row count? so this will lead to performance lose ?

Comment: @Dogan I'll bet that the SQL Server optimizer is smart enough to recognize that the subqueries on the `TableA` and `TableB` tables are _uncorrelated_ to the outer query on the `TableC` table.  As such, it will run the subqueries only once and then cache away the counts somewhere.  So, my answer is more efficient than you might think.